# string split with delimiter \t

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
while 1:
    line = file.readline()
    if not line: break
    linenum += 1
    line = line.splitlines()[0]
    token = line.split('\t')
```

and this is a screenshot showing the local variables displayed in the debugger window:

[image: screenshot of debugger variables]

As you can see in debugger's image, line isn't split.
Why this is happening? I tried a regular expression but split still doesn't work.

Comment: That is not code, it's colourful image :/

Comment: `"Can't\treproduce".split('\t')`

Comment: This is not a tab character in your original input.

Comment: As a side note, you can replace the first four lines of your code with just `for linenum, line in enumerate(file):`. Or, if you don't need `linenum`, just `for line in file:`.

Comment: More importantly, `line.splitlines()[0]` is probably not what you want. If you're just trying to strip off the newline at the end, just use `line.rstrip()` or `line.rstrip('\n')`. If you have a file with, say, Unix `\n` newlines as the real newlines, but also classic-Mac `\r` newlines in the middle of each line, and you want to throw out everything after the first `\r`, then your code is correct, but otherwise, it's confusing (and inefficient, but that's not likely to matter as much).

Comment: @abarnert: For the record, `for linenum, line in enumerate(file):` is not an exact replacement for the first four lines of OP's code.

Comment: @martineau: Well, sure, if `linenum` weren't `0` in some earlier code he didn't show us. Or if `file` weren't really a file-like object, but some weird thing that happens to have a `readline` method anyway. Or if he has an `else` on the `while` loop that he hasn't shown us. But it's very likely to be a perfect replacement in the context of any likely real code. And it wouldn't be hard to change it in any of those cases anyway (e.g., pass a start to `enumerate`, or `iter(f.readline, '')`, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is not in your code, but in your input file, It contains `'\\t'` (that is, backslash and t letter) instead of `'\t'`.

Weird "capital W with strikethrough" is actually a [backslash displayed in a wrong way](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3f0a4f84-53c7-4468-9c79-6770ee83b2f7/backslashes-are-printing-as-capital-with-strikethrough-how-can-i-fix-this?forum=vssetup).